# Error saying Mail class not found when sending email in Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

I get this error when I try to call Laravel's Mail:send method.

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Internal Server Error",
"debug":{"code":1,"message":"Class 'MyMail\\Mail' not found",..
```

All the settings in app/config/mail.php has been verified to be working.

```
namespace MyMail;

class GetMyMail extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function sendMail()
    {
        //$json_data is data stored in json
        $users = json_decode($json_data, true);

        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            Mail::send('template1', $user, function($message) use ($user)
            {

                $message->to($user['email'], $user['first_name'])
                        ->subject('Laravel Email Test');
            });       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your code is under a namespace, you have to import the Mail facade (I'm guessing you just forgot this):

```
namespace MyMail;

use Mail;

class GetMyMail extends Controller
{
    // your code
}
```

Or, if you prefer, you can just prefix it with a backslash:

```
\Mail::send('template1', $user, function($message) use ($user)
{
   $message->to($user['email'], $user['first_name'])->subject('Laravel Email Test');
});
```

Comment: @kejetons Actually tried that with use Mail; but it still doesn't work and it works if I removed all namespace. How can I get it to work as I need the namespace.

Comment: Are you sure that you've posted the full code? This definitely should have fixed your problem.

Comment: @kejetons for this file there are some other other codes but it is only to query database and convert data into json format ($users) and a the foreach is in a try catch which I omitted. I tried it again strangely I am able to get a message email sent but no emails was received.

Comment: If you didn't receive any email, that might be because you're in the development mode and `pretend` option in configuration is set to `true`;

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the Mail Class.

add

```
use Mail;
```

afer the namespace declaration, that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't why nobody answers this but I'm sure they just forgot:

```
\Mail::send();
```

Note the "\" before "Mail". Applies to all other static class usage inside a namespace.